# How to use objectFit for Next.js 13 <Image>?

Tags: image, next.js, object-fit

In the [next/image docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) under version history, it states the following for v13.0.0:

> layout, objectFit, objectPosition, lazyBoundary, lazyRoot props removed.

Under next/image docs for [fill](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#fill) the documentation states we can set the object fit with `object-fit: "contain"` or alternatively to `object-fit: "cover"`. I am unable to set the object fit to cover with the following code:

```
<div className="relative">
  <Image
      src=""
      alt=""
      fill={true}
      layout="fill"
      object-fit="cover"
    />
</div>
```

How does one implement [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with Next.js 13?

Comment: You set it through CSS directly. For instance, you could do: `style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#style.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

NextJS Image component now supports style prop so I believe this is the right answer:

```
<div style={{position:"relative"}}>
  <Image
      src={source}
      alt=""
      fill
      style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
    />
</div>
```

Parent container is relatively positioned.

Comment: This saved my life - thank you. It feels like the docs on this one aren't very well explained.

Comment: Also, I liked the old way of just defining height and width as an aspect ratio like height="3" width="4". This new way of strictly defining height and width seems dumb.

Comment: It really is lame. I did the same thing - using height/width to inject the image ratio then layout="responsive" to size to parent. I have all my images in markdown files and the codemod doesn't run on markdown. Ugh - I have hundreds of images to fix. Python here I come :(

Comment: "Parent container is relatively positioned." hahaha wowza

Answer (score 6):

In next.js 13, both *objectFit* and *layout* prop are deprecated from the Image component and must be implemented with *style* or *className*. *Fill* is a boolean that is false if not applied and true if present.

```
<div className="relative">
  <Image
      src="/"
      alt="logo"
      fill
      style={{objectFit:"contain"}}
    />
</div>
```

***References:***

- https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-upgrade-to-13
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Answer (score 3):

Next v13 no longer supports `objectFit="contain"` in the Image component. The best option is using the style props.

```
<div className="relative">
  <Image
      src=""
      alt=""
      fill
      style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is the only one which is updated (October 2023)

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue. I was able to solve it by using it like this.

```
<div className="relative">
 <Image
  src={source}
  alt=""
  fill={true}
  layout={'fill'}
  objectFit={'cover'}
 />
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For the tailwind users:

```js
<Image src="foo.png" alt="foo" className="object-cover" />
```

Of course, 'cover' can be replaced with whatever object size (fit, contain) you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

`objectFit` attribute still works in in next 13.5 as long as it's defined together with `layout`.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import src from './image.jpg'

<Image
  src={src}
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="cover"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

style={{objectFit: "contain"}}

[Next Js Doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image)

sample:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        src="/profile.png"
        width={500}
        height={500}
        alt="Picture of the author"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```